# Updating GITLAB from 3.1 to 4.0 rake error

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to update my GITLAB. I have been following [this article](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/From-3.1-to-4.0) and I got stuck on this command:

```
sudo -u gitlab -H bundle exec rake gitlab:enable_namespaces RAILS_ENV=production --trace
```

The output is this:

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'gitlab:enable_namespaces'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:49:in `[]'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:140:in `invoke_task'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `each'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:99:in `block in top_level'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `run_with_threads'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `top_level'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:71:in `block in run'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:158:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:68:in `run'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.1/bin/rake:37:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```